# Swift: Change row height of UITableViewCell which have UIWebView inside it

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiwebview

I have two cells in a UITableView. One have a webview which loads data from an HTML string

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell4", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell4
        let htmlHeight = contentHeights[indexPath.row]

        cell.webElement.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.webElement.delegate = self
        cell.webElement.loadHTMLString(HTMLContent, baseURL: nil)
        cell.webElement.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, htmlHeight)

        return cell
```

and 2nd one Loads a URL

```
let htmlHeight = contentHeights[indexPath.row]
        self.commentSection = cell.commentsView
        self.commentSection.tag = indexPath.row
        self.commentSection.delegate = self
        let url = NSURL(string: commentsURL)
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url! )
        self.commentSection.loadRequest(requestObj)
        self.commentSection.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, htmlHeight)
```

Using some help from internet, I got a function of delegate which can be served for this purpose:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView)
{

    if (contentHeights[webView.tag] == webView.scrollView.contentSize.height)
    {

      return
    }
    webView.frame.size.height = 1
    webView.frame.size = webView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeZero)
    contentHeights[webView.tag] = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height

    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: webView.tag, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    }}
```

But this only works for 1st row which loads data from HTML String and so the first row changes it's height according to the webcontent.
But for the second row, the row height refreshes for two times and before finishing it's URL loading and stucks on a small row height.

Can anyone help me with this???

Comment: You can resolve the issue?